# R - counting adjacent duplicate items

Tags: r, count, duplicates

New to R and would like to do the following operation:
I have a set of numbers e.g. (1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1) and need to count adjacent duplicates as they occur. The result I am looking for is:

2,1,3,2,1

as in 2 ones, 1 zero, 3 ones, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rle`

```
rle(v1)$lengths
#[1] 2 1 3 2 1
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
```